# Assets on ZF2 project

Tags: php, zend-framework2, assets

I try to use Assets on my ZF2 project.
I found this module.

[RWOverdijk / AssetManager](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager/blob/master/src/AssetManager/Module.php)

But I notice this:

```
$response->setStatusCode(200);
```

Is there any way to return 304 too?

Comment: can you explain what do you want to do? the asset manager returns a 304 ( file AssetManager.php - line 141 ) otherwise force a 304 with ``$response->setStatusCode(304);``

Comment: No, the files (js, css, png ...) always returns 200. And the browser load  the files again.